# Custome adapter for list view and change images

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am faching data from server and passing this data to custom adapter to display it on image adapter i am using asynchtask for faching data my problem is taht i want to change image in list view after every 5 seconds please suggest me a solution here is my activity file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private String[] image,name,descr;
    ListView list;
    LazyImageLoadAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String serverURL = "http://10.0.2.2/JsonReturn.php";

        // Use AsyncTask execute Method To Prevent ANR Problem
        new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);
        // Create custom adapter for listview


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // Remove adapter refference from list
        list.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //Refresh cache directory downloaded images
            adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };


    public void onItemClick(int mPosition)
    {
        String tempValues = image[mPosition];

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                "Image URL : "+tempValues, 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
    }

    private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        // Required initialization
        ListView lst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        String data =""; 
        //TextView uiUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
      ///  TextView jsonParsed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonParsed);
        int sizeData = 0;  
       // EditText serverText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverText);


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            //Start Progress Dialog (Message)

            Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            Dialog.show();

            try{
                // Set Request parameter
                data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8")+ "="+"RAja";//serverText.getText();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
            BufferedReader reader=null;

                 // Send data 
                try
                { 

                   // Defined URL  where to send data
                   URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                  // Send POST data request

                  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
                  conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
                  wr.write( data ); 
                  wr.flush(); 

                  // Get the server response 

                  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  String line = null;

                    // Read Server Response
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                               // Append server response in string
                               sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }

                    // Append Server Response To Content String 
                   Content = sb.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Error = ex.getMessage();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {

                        reader.close();
                    }

                    catch(Exception ex) {}
                }

            /*****************************************************/
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            // Close progress dialog
            Dialog.dismiss();

            if (Error != null) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error"+Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                //uiUpdate.setText("Output : "+Error);

            } else {

                // Show Response Json On Screen (activity)
                //uiUpdate.setText( Content );
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "content"+Content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;


             /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/

                String OutputData = "";
                JSONObject jsonResponse;

                try {

                     /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
                     jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

                     /***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. ***/
                     /*******  Returns null otherwise.  *******/
                     JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

                     /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/


                     int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();  
                     image=new String[lengthJsonArr];
                     name=new String[lengthJsonArr];
                     descr=new String[lengthJsonArr];
                     for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) 
                     {
                         /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                         JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                         /******* Fetch node values **********/
                         String nm       = jsonChildNode.optString("name").toString();
                         String img     = jsonChildNode.optString("image").toString();
                         String desc = jsonChildNode.optString("desc").toString();

                         image[i]=img;
                         name[i]=nm;
                         descr[i]=desc;
                         OutputData += " Name           : "+ nm +" \n "
                                     + "Number      : "+ img +" \n "
                                     + "Time                : "+ desc +" \n " 
                                     +"--------------------------------------------------\n";

                         //Log.i("JSON parse", song_name);
                    }
                 /****************** End Parse Response JSON Data *************/     

                     //Show Parsed Output on screen (activity)
                     //jsonParsed.setText( OutputData );
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Parsed Data"+ OutputData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                     adapter=new LazyImageLoadAdapter(MainActivity.this, image,name,descr);

                     //Set adapter to listview
                     list.setAdapter(adapter);
                     //lst.setAdapter(adapter);
                 } catch (JSONException e) {

                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }


             }
        }

    }



}
```

and my image adapter class file is as follow

```
public class LazyImageLoadAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data,name,desc;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Activity a, String[] d,String[] name,String[] desc) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        this.name=name;
        this.desc=desc;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Create ImageLoader object to download and show image in list
        // Call ImageLoader constructor to initialize FileCache
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView text;
        public TextView text1;
        public TextView textWide;
        public ImageView image;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

           /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag( holder );
        }
        else 
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();


        holder.text.setText(name[position]);
        holder.text1.setText(desc[position]);
        ImageView image = holder.image;

        //DisplayImage function from ImageLoader Class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);

        /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    /********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
    private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
        private int mPosition;

       OnItemClickListener(int position){
             mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            MainActivity sct = (MainActivity)activity;
            sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
        }               
    }   
}
```

i have tried to put set adapter() method in oncreate() of activity but it gives me error so how can i change images display on list view after some specific time please suggest solution

Comment: Error is that when i use list.setAdapter(adapter) in onCreate() of activity it gives NullPointer Exception So i have to use list.setAdapter(adapter) in AsynchTask LongOperation class

Comment: and i also want to change images of list view after every 5 sec

Comment: Where do you initialize the adapter?

Comment: I have initlized adapter in AsynchTAsk Class LongOperatin

Comment: From where you getting the images to display on listview after specific time? Are you getting them from web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set the adapter only one time and when update the data you should only the call the method of adapter `notifydatasetchange()`

in your code make a `bool` variable `isFirsttime` and keep it initially true

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Parsed Data"+ OutputData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


if(isFirsttime)

{    
adapter=new LazyImageLoadAdapter(MainActivity.this, image,name,descr);

       //Set adapter to listview

       list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

else{

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Make `isFirsttime` `bool` variable globally and set it true
i hope it will help you

Comment: Ya ur suggestion is usefull but then how can i change dataset after every 5 seconds and longoperation class is going to call only once so that is not possible to put notifyDatasetchanged in that class so where can i make changes

Comment: make isFirsttime static in MainActivity class

Comment: I want to add adapter in onCreate() method of MainActivity But it Gives nullPointerException Plz frnd help me

Comment: use this get() method with your Aysnc calll then set adapter in oncreate so i hope you will not get the error. LongOperation().execute(serverURL).get()